# How do I interpret the following error I've received?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I'm working on a project so that I can become more familiar with writing code.  I'm a beginner and wish to understand as much as I possibly can.  I don't believe I have any spelling errors.  Will someone explain what is wrong the code I have so far?
[I received this error message: "import and export may only appear at the top level."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtELf.png)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";`enter code here`
import pet, { ANIMALS } from "@frontendmasters/pet";
import Results from './Results';
import useDropdown from "./useDropdown";

const SearchParams = () => {
    const [location, setLocation] = useState("Seattle, WA");
    const [breeds, setBreeds] = useState([]);
    const [animal, AnimalDropdown] = useDropdown("Animal", "dog", ANIMALS);
    const [breed, BreedDropdown, setBreed] = useDropdown("Breed", "", breeds);
    const [pets, setPets] = useState([]);
};
async function requestPets() {
    const { animals } = await pet.animals({
        location,
        breed,
        type: animal
    });

    setPets(animals || []);
}

useEffect(() => {
    setBreeds([]);
    setBreed("");

    pet.breeds(animal).then(({ breeds: apiBreeds }) => {
        const breedStrings = apiBreeds.map(({ name }) => name);
        setBreeds(breedStrings);
        [animal, setBreed, setBreeds]
    });

    return (
        <div className="search-params">
            <form
                onSubmit={e => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    requestPets();
                }
                } >
                <label htmlFor="location">
                    Location
                   <input
                        id="location"
                        value={location}
                        placeholder="Location"
                        onChange={e => setLocation(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </label>
                <AnimalDropdown />
                <BreedDropdown />
                <button>Submit</button>
            </form>
                <Results pets={pets} />enter code here
        </div >
    );


    export default SearchParams;
```

Comment: `})` is missing before export

Comment: To understand the problem statement can you paste the error you are getting ..it'll be much more easier for me to make you undersatand the problem that you are stucked with. Just by taking an overview all i can say that there's a missing }) before the export. Happy coding :-)

Comment: @Code Maniac, I found that I was indeed missing closing braces and such. I appreciate you taking the time to help me out.  I even downloaded eslint, especially since I'm using useEffect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to export in `useEffect` function. I think you missed to close it. And also you close requestPets before `useEFfect` which is not also correct. I suggest you use eslint.

I think it is supposed to be something like this?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";`enter code here`
import pet, { ANIMALS } from "@frontendmasters/pet";
import Results from './Results';
import useDropdown from "./useDropdown";

const SearchParams = () => {
    const [location, setLocation] = useState("Seattle, WA");
    const [breeds, setBreeds] = useState([]);
    const [animal, AnimalDropdown] = useDropdown("Animal", "dog", ANIMALS);
    const [breed, BreedDropdown, setBreed] = useDropdown("Breed", "", breeds);
    const [pets, setPets] = useState([]);

async function requestPets() {
    const { animals } = await pet.animals({
        location,
        breed,
        type: animal
    });
    setPets(animals || []);
}

useEffect(() => {
    setBreeds([]);
    setBreed("");

    pet.breeds(animal).then(({ breeds: apiBreeds }) => {
        const breedStrings = apiBreeds.map(({ name }) => name);
        setBreeds(breedStrings);
        [animal, setBreed, setBreeds]
    });
});

    return (
        <div className="search-params">
            <form
                onSubmit={e => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    requestPets();
                }
                } >
                <label htmlFor="location">
                    Location
                   <input
                        id="location"
                        value={location}
                        placeholder="Location"
                        onChange={e => setLocation(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </label>
                <AnimalDropdown />
                <BreedDropdown />
                <button>Submit</button>
            </form>
                <Results pets={pets} />enter code here
        </div >
    );
}
    export default SearchParams;
```

Comment: Yes, I used eslint as you suggested and had a couple of missing closing braces.  Your answer was helpful so I really appreciate that.